# Adding Separate Sections in phpMyAdmin

Tags: php, mysql

I am having a problem allowing users (teachers) to have their own sections. A section will allow a teacher that registers access to only their students and questions posted by them. When a teacher registers, they will be given a unique number that allows them access to a new separate section.

I have one users table that is filled with students and teachers. I tried adding another column or table for students and teachers with the same section number but I have not been able to get it to work.

Also the id I am using in phpMyAdmin, I am using as a student id number. I tried to use it as a section number which took away the ability to recognize each students' answers in my database (since they are stored as an id).  I hope this is clear and thank you all ahead of time.

Here is my users table in my database.

[image]

And here is my register.php code...it is deprecated as of now (working on switching it to mysqli later)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Registration</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
</head>

<body class="login" style="margin-bottom: 100px; " >

    <?php include 'connect.php'; ?>

    <?php include 'functions.php'; ?>

<span style="display: inline-block;"><h1 style="margin-left: 40px; ">Register</h1></span><span style="display: inline-block; padding-left: 165px; "><a href="login.php"><p>Back</p></a></span>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">

<form action="" method="post">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <input type="text" name="username" class="box" size="25" placeholder="Username"><br>
        </li>
        <li>
            <input type="password" name="password" class="box" size="25" placeholder="Password"><br>
        </li>
            <br><br>
            <button type="submit" style="margin-bottom: 5px;" class="subbutton" name="submit">Register</button>
        </li>
    </ul>   
</form>

    <?php

            if(isset($_POST["submit"])){

            if(!empty($_POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['password'])) {
            $username=$_POST['username'];
            $password=$_POST['password'];

            $con=mysql_connect('localhost','root','') or die(mysql_error());
            mysql_select_db('project') or die("Cannot select database");

            $query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='".$username."'");
            $numrows=mysql_num_rows($query);
            if($numrows==0)
            {
            $sql="INSERT INTO users VALUES('','$username','$password','','','','1','d')";

            $result=mysql_query($sql);


            if($result){
            echo "Account successfully created!";
            } else {
            echo "Didn\'t work, try again";
            }

            } else {
            echo "That user ID already exists! Please try again";
            }

            } else {
            echo "All fields are required!";
        }
    }

    ?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The `mysql_*` functions in PHP are deprecated and shouldn't be used. Please read [Why shouldn't I use mysql_* functions in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php) for information on why and what to replace them with.

Comment: Yea I know, I have a lot of `mysql_*` code that is deprecated. I am working on switching to `mysqli` later. Thank you for the link to help.